# Creating a mean of columns with csv writer

Tags: python, csv, mean

I'm trying to generate a mean of two columns that is saved using a csv writer. I have response times and whether the answer was correct or not.

Code:

```
stimTime = time.time()
if thisKey in ['a']:
    pmResponse = time.time()
    pmTime = pmResponse - stimTime
    print pmTime
    if sampled_word == sampled_word.upper():
        pmCue = "correct"
    else:
        print "incorrect"
    prospective_response = (pmTime, pmCue)
    with open (info['participant']+"pm", 'ab') as csvfile:
        wr = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        wr.writerow(prospective_response)
```

The text file data therefore comes out like:

```
0.5339999198913574,correct
1.0839998722076416,correct
1.234234, incorrect
```

So I'm trying to work out how to how to create a mean of the two columns and also have that written at the end of the csv file. I understand that I will have to change to correct and incorrect into numerical form.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sum the times and cues as you go, add a counter to count how many rows you write, and at the end write out sum/count to get a mean average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add in this code:

```
totalResponse += pmTime
rowCounter += 1
if sampled_word == sampled_word.upper():
    pmCue = "correct"
    correct += 1
else:
    print "incorrect"
```

and at the end of everything:

```
with open (info['participant']+"pm", 'ab') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    wr.writerow(correct/float(rowCounter),totalResponse/rowCounter)
```

Comment: Thank you very much kabanus!

Comment: Please read the tour, and accept the reply so future readers can see.